# Javascript: Event inside a function object created with the new keyword

Tags: javascript, events, object, com, activexobject

I have a C# COM DLL ("This.That") that has events, which I've tested using JS and they work fine. I'm now trying to wrap all my tested code inside an object. The following example works fine:

```
var oTest = new Test();

function Test()
{
    var oDevice = new ActiveXObject("This.That");

    this.CancelOperation = function()
    {
        try
        {
            oDevice.CancelOperation();
            return "CancelOperation successful.";
        }
        catch (e)
        {
            return e.message;
        }
    };
}
```

But once I try to add an event to it, it doesn't work. It looks like it's probably bad syntax. I can't find any resources online that explain how this is done.

```
var oTest = new Test();

function Test()
{
    var oDevice = new ActiveXObject("This.That");

    this.CancelOperation = function()
    {
        try
        {
            oDevice.CancelOperation();
            return "CancelOperation successful.";
        }
        catch (e)
        {
            return e.message;
        }
    };

    oDevice::DeviceStatusUpdate(wasSuccess, message, data) = function()
    {
        document.getElementById("outBox").value += "Success: " + wasSuccess.toString() + "\nMessage: " + message + "\nData:" + data + "\n\n";
    };
}
```

Comment: I think this is not JavaScript: `oDevice::DeviceStatusUpdate(wasSuccess, message, data) = function()`?

Comment: Not valid JS  oDevice::DeviceStatusUpdate(wasSuccess, message, data)

Comment: Teemu & Gurpreet, that's what I figured but I don't know how to get the event handler working inside the object. Any suggestions?

Comment: new ActiveXObject("This.That"); ? what should this do??

Comment: @philipp, that's a COM object. It has events I'm trying to implement in the oTest object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've gotten something working but I'd still like to see other answers. This puts the event handler outside of the JS file and into the document, but the code itself is still inside the JS file. The organization of the code was my greatest concern so this is acceptable to me.

```
var oTest = new Test();

function Test()
{
    var oDevice = new ActiveXObject("This.That");

    this.CancelOperation = function()
    {
        try
        {
            oDevice.CancelOperation();
            return "CancelOperation successful.";
        }
        catch (e)
        {
            return e.message;
        }
    };

    this.WireEvents = function()
    {
        var script = document.createElement("script");
        script.type = "text/javascript";
        script.text = 'function oTest.oDevice::DeviceStatusUpdate(wasSuccess, message, data) { document.getElementById("outBox").value += "Success: " + wasSuccess.toString() + "\\nMessage: " + message + "\\nData:" + data + "\\n\\n"; }';
        document.body.appendChild(script);
    };
}
```